# Moving a ball with help of accelerometer in android and Smooth in Acceleration

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView = null;
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
    public float xPosition, xAcceleration, xVelocity = 0.0f;
    public float yPosition, yAcceleration, yVelocity = 0.0f;
    public float xmax, ymax;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Bitmap mWood;
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    public float frameTime = 0.666f;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set FullScreen & portrait
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // Get a reference to a SensorManager
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
        setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Calculate Boundry
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        xmax = (float) display.getWidth() - 50;
        ymax = (float) display.getHeight() - 50;
    }

    // This method will update the UI on new sensor events
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
                // Set sensor values as acceleration
                yAcceleration = sensorEvent.values[1];
                xAcceleration = sensorEvent.values[2];
                updateBall();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateBall() {

        // Calculate new speed
        xVelocity += (xAcceleration * frameTime);
        yVelocity += (yAcceleration * frameTime);

        // Calc distance travelled in that time
        float xS = (xVelocity / 2) * frameTime;
        float yS = (yVelocity / 2) * frameTime;

        // Add to position negative due to sensor
        // readings being opposite to what we want!
        xPosition -= xS;
        yPosition -= yS;

        if (xPosition > xmax) {
            xPosition = xmax;
        } else if (xPosition < 0) {
            xPosition = 0;
        }
        if (yPosition > ymax) {
            yPosition = ymax;
        } else if (yPosition < 0) {
            yPosition = 0;
        }
    }

    // I've chosen to not implement this method
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unregister the listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
        public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ball);
            final int dstWidth = 50;
            final int dstHeight = 50;
            mBitmap = Bitmap
                    .createScaledBitmap(ball, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmap;
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, xPosition, yPosition, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

The ball seems to be freezed not moving no motion it is detecting.
Also the ball should be smooth in acceleration on moving the device.
Please help me with this code and try to explain as easy as possible since i am new to android.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did it but the ball is going out of boundary. Please help me how to do put boundary condition since ball is going out of boundary and please do tell me how to increase ball speed it is really slow